# Moving on deep function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, break, continue

I have a short question: How can I move from `A` to `B` in this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    B <--------------- So far
    if (/*condition*/)
    {                   
        if(/*condition*/)
        {                       
            .....
        }
        else {
            A  <------------ From here
        };
    }
    else if(/*condition*/)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know about `break` and `continue`, but it doesn't work here

Thanks all!

Comment: you can use `continue;`

Comment: That's where it's going to go anyway with what you provided.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work in this"?

Comment: My guess is that `A` only happens on the last iteration of the loop (`i` is `length-1`).

Comment: `continue` works. You're being wrong. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use goto.js (http://summerofgoto.com/) to handle this with the exact loop that you're trying to use, but you should consider just finding a different way to factor your code.

Comment: continue works in the OP's code. I don't know what OP is talking about.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really oddly worded question. Thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: Downvote is because I think it's a bad idea to give a really complex answer/suggestion when the OP clearly has a very basic misunderstanding going on.  If someone doesn't know how to add two numbers, you don't recommend  jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion

```
for(var i=0;i<length;i++) {
    someFunc(i);   
}

function someFunc(i){
    if (/*condition*/){                   
        if(/*condition*/) {     
        } else {
            return someFunc(i) //change i  to prevent infinite loop
        }
    } else if(/*condition*/ ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like an infinite recursion if it gets to that point... unless something in the conditions is changing within an iteration

Comment: no. it is concept code. In your concept code you'd get also a infinite jumps

Comment: OP is being incredibly unclear. continue works.

Comment: In that way the code is simpler to refactor and write tests, but you are right

Comment: continue and break would break or go to next iteration... I presumed that was the problem to solve